# Envio de correos con laravel

Tags: laravel, email

Estoy enviando correos a través de laravel y mi hosting en Hostgator.

Tengo bien configurada la cuenta

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.mycompany.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=no-reply@mycompany.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=estosdatosnosonreales
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=SSL
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=no-reply@mycompany.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${estos datos no son los normales}"
```

Envió el correo de la siguiente forma.

```
Mail::send(
  'mailings::'.$scheduling->html_email->view_path,
   [],
   function($msj) {
      $msj->from('no-reply@mycompany.com', 'estos datos no son los normales');
      $msj->subject('prueba');
      $msj->to('xdxd@gmail.com');
   }
);
```

No me sale ningún error en laravel pero nunca recibo el correo en gmail. Sin embargo si mando el correo al mismo servidor es decir si envió un correo a una dirección que termine en **mycompany.com** si lo envía.

Ahora si mando el correo directamente del cliente de correo a gmail si llagan al momento.

Comment: gmail tiene me parece una configuración extra para *aplicaciones no seguras* y me parece por default esta deshabilitada y en consecuencia se debe habilitar ¿ya probaste eso?

Comment: Revisa la carpeta de SPAM también

Comment: @BetaM Tengo configurado como proveedor mi cuenta de Hostgator. (desde este servidor hago los envíos).

Comment: @LeoLopez Si revisé el spam pero no aparecen los correos